# What kind of tiny green bugs are these on mulberries?

Tags: bugs, mulberry

I will try to take a picture next time I see them, but they were thin and green and there would be a few of them crawling around a single mulberry. As I recall, the length of their bodies was hardly as long as the individual drupelets on the mulberry, if that. So they just look kind of like little green slivers gliding about at a moderate pace because I couldn't see the feet even though they must have had them based on the way they moved.

And just to clarify 'thin', I mean proportionally their bodies were long compared to the width.

Comment: We really need a picture to identify the problem

Comment: Agreed. However, they might be aphids or leafhoppers. I don't know of too many other critters that size that are green.

Comment: @Brōtsyorfuzthrāx Yes, some of the pictures of aphids I'm finding are very similar though maybe not exactly the same as what I recall. Interestingly I didn't see any when I picked a few more the next day. I'll try again and see if I can find more to take a picture of though.

Comment: Do they jump or fly?

Comment: @Brōtsyorfuzthrāx nope, just looked like they were crawling at the pace of a disturbed ant (relatively speaking... ants are bigger so they would move faster, obviously). And they were just crawling around and around.